# angularjs - different Modules in different Files and different directories

Tags: angularjs

I would like to split my angular app in different modules, because it is getting bigger and bigger.

In the main module I have this code which is in the directory app/js/app.js

```
angular.module('mainApp', ['subApp']);
```

The subModule I have in the directory app/components/business/business.js

```
angular.module('subApp', []);
```

If I start my app now, I get the error `Uncaught Error: No module: subApp`

If I put the subApp in the file of the mainApp, it works fine.

Can you tell me, what I have to do so that angular finds the subApp in the different directory?

Comment: Have you tried reordering of script declaration\reference within your html.

Answer (score 0):

The file that contains `angular.module('subApp', []);` need to be loaded before you hit the statement `angular.module('mainApp', ['subApp']);`

Comment: ok i included the file with the subApp module at the html file. now i finds the subApp, but i get the error, that the controller of the supApp is missing. I'm using the subApp controller in the $routeProvider.when... of the mainApp. is there something else i have to do?

Comment: how are you using $routeProvider. A code sample would be useful preferably in a separate question with an appropriate title

Comment: code in mainAPP:

var myModule = angular.module('mainAPP', ['subAPP']);
myModule.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/test', {templateUrl: 'components/test/test-list.html', controller: SubAppCtrl});}]);
 

code in subAPP:

var myapp = angular.module('subAPP', []);
myapp.controller('SubAppCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$translate', function ($scope, $rootScope, $translate){
..
]);